# Laravel 4 settings controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm really new to Laravel, so I have this question:

If I have 2 tables in the database, say: positions and vectors and I want to be able
to edit/add/update/delete them, what kind of model/controller/view structure do I need?

Am I off with creating controllers for both positions and vectors?
Should I create a Settings controller and just create the models for positions and vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all up to you really, but I would have a model for each, a repository for all the logic, probably called `SettingsRepository.php` and then just use that repository for wherever you need to use that code.  You'd also have to modify your `composer.json` file and make sure the folder you are putting your repositories in is in the `autoload` section.

As for your controllers, you'd probably only need one which would grab the data from the repository and insert it into the view.  When I think of settings, I think of settings you'd need in other areas of your app as well and with the repository, all that information would be easily accessible to other controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Models handle the direct interactions with your database.  Create a "Position" model and a "Vector" model.  When you do, you will extend the Eloquent model, and you will quickly have a model that knows how to add, delete, update, save, etc.
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Create one view for each page you want the user to see.  (You'll create master template views eventually, but don't worry about this for now).
http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views

Controllers juggle the data between the views and the models.  There is a section on this in the Laravel docs but I don't have enough rep points to post more than 2 links.

Group your controller functionality in a way that makes the most sense.  If all of your website routes are going to start with "/settings", that a red flag that you might just need one "settings" controller.

Here is an extremely simplified example of what you might be wanting to do.  There are a lot of different ways to accomplish what you are wanting.  This is one example.

```
// View that you see when you go to www.yoursite.com/position/create
// [stored in the "views" folder, named create-position.php]
<html><body>
<form method="post" action="/position/create">
    <input type="text" name="x_coord">
    <input type="text" name="y_coord">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body></html>


// Routing [in your "routes.php" file]
// register your controller as www.yoursite.com/position
// any public method will be avaliable at www.yoursite.com/methodname
Route::controller('position', 'PositionController');


// Your Position Controller
// [stored in the "controllers" folder, in "PositionController.php" file
// the "get" "post" etc at the beginning of a method name is the HTTP verb used to access that method.
class PositionController extends BaseController {

    public function getCreate()
    {
        return View::make('create-position');
    }

    public function postCreate()
    {
        $newPosition = Position::create(array(
            'x_coord' => Input::get('x_coord'),
            'y_coord' => Input::get('y_coord')
        ));

        return Redirect::to('the route that shows the newly created position');
    }

}

// Your Position Model
class Position extends Eloquent {

    // the base class "Eloquent" does a lot of the heavy lifting here.

    // just tell it which columns you want to be able to mass-assign
    protected $fillable = array('x_coord', 'y_coord');

    // yes, nothing else required, it already knows how to handle data

}
```